# How to use keys in Django's internationalization?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117481/best-practice-for-localizing-long-text-in-django), Django uses the `default language` strings to translate to other languages. This might be perfect in most situations, in my case, however, I would like to use keys instead (i.e. `usermanager.models.userprofile.help_text.user_type`. Reason is, that the text will change very often and I'd like the source code to not being touched as this use case IMHO does not relate to software development.

Instead, `rosetta` shall be used for maintaining the strings.

What is the best practice to do this in Django, could a "fake" language be an idea?

Comment: what do you mean by this  `usermanager.models.userprofile.help_text.user_type`  what is this?

Comment: you want to use the msgid instead of msgstr?